# How to read file from WSO2 ESB without using poll interval

Tags: readfile, vfs, wso2-esb

I am able to read the file from specified READFILEURI path if I can specify the poll interval.

My current requirement is to read the file from given path only when we trigger the proxy service.It should not poll the file automatically.When I click on "try this service" and send the request then only the file should read from the read file path and do processing.

TO test this I have removed the "transport.vfs.pollInterval" attribute from my proxy configuration and tested it.But file is not getting read from the path once I trigger the proxy request.

Could some one help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work if you use the file connector.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector

You should be able to create a simple proxy that get's triggered via http/https and the uses the above mentioned file connector read operation to read the file.

Unfortunately I cannot give you an exact example because we're still on an older esb version where this connector isn't available.

Hope that helps.

Regards
Martin